# Give a std::string to StreamWriter to write a txt file

Tags: c++-cli, streamwriter, std

I want give a string as a argument to the Stream Writer writeline method in visual c++

```
StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter("Positive Sample.txt");

string Loc = "blabla";

sw->WriteLine(Loc);
```

It generating a error - no instance of overload function match the argument list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WriteLine` method accepts CLI's String, and not std's string.

```
StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter("Positive Sample.txt");

String^ Loc = "blabla";

sw->WriteLine(Loc);
```

You can use `System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi`to marshal from C string to `String`, or you can pass C string into String's constructor:

```
string Loc = "blabla";
String^ strLoc = gcnew String(Loc.c_str());
```

**EDIT**

As Ben pointed out in the comments, you should use `marshal_as` instead `PtrToStringAnsi`:

Example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx) (inverse operation could be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx))

```
// marshal_as_test.cpp
// compile with: /clr
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main() {
   const char* message = "Test String to Marshal";
   String^ result;
   result = marshal_as<String^>( message );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, avoid `PtrToStringAnsi`.  C++/CLI has the much better `marshal_as` template framework.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you, I will add note. I am not C++/CLI expert, so I've googled around, but PtrToStringAnsi was the in the first few results.

Comment: Unfortunately, much of the online information about C++/CLI was written by people who aren't familiar with it, and found one hacky solution, without even realizing there was a cleaner way.  The reverse conversion is especially bad, with a number of highly voted answers on SO doing it badly (on questions where both methods are presented while the question is still open, the `marshal_as` approach wins by a landslide)

Comment: When im trying to inlclude marshal.h header file a error coming WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS' : undeclared identifier. i tried to solve it by using stack overflow replies but failed. help me.

Comment: @Wolverin_rox Try including <windows.h>.

Comment: ty, I used fstream instead of stream writer it worked perfectly fine ty again.............